Getting error while running apt-get update
dpkg: error processing package php8.1-mbstring (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
php8.1-common
php8.1-imap
php8.1-gd
php8.1-phpdbg
php8.1-pgsql
php8.1
php8.1-curl
php8.1-xml
php8.1-mysql
php8.1-cli
php8.1-dev
php8.1-zip
php8.1-readline
libapache2-mod-php8.1
php8.1-cgi
php8.1-opcache
php8.1-ldap
php8.1-bz2
php8.1-mbstring
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


I suggest you read your actual messages; you've pasted only the final summary details that are intended to grab your attention and have you read the full report. We're limited to details you provided; so cannot read the full messages & command that led to the issue which you can.

You forgot to explain what you’ve tried before copy/pasting (part of) the error here.

Is this the tutorial you followed?
